# How to export csv gravity forms to local path on submission?

Tags: forms, csv, export, code-snippets, gravity

I create a snippet for gravity forms, but cannot export .csv to my  path.
Please help me?

This is code:

/* export CSV to local path */

```
add_action('gform_entry_created', 'create_csv', 30, 2);
function create_csv($entry_id, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 1) {
        $name = isset($_POST['item_meta'][1]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][1] : '';
        $target = isset($_POST['item_meta'][2]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][2] : '';
        $email = isset($_POST['item_meta'][3]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][3] : '';
        $date = isset($_POST['item_meta'][6]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][6] : '';
        $time = isset($_POST['item_meta'][7]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][7] : '';
        $Subject = isset($_POST['item_meta'][4]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][4] : '';
        $Message = isset($_POST['item_meta'][5]) ? $_POST['item_meta'][5] : '';
        $header = "name,target,email,date,time,Subject,Message\n";
        $data = "$name,$target,$email,$date,$time,$Subject,$Message\n";
        $fileName = dirname(__DIR__, 3) . "/demoweb" . $name . "-" .$time . "-request" . ".csv";

        
        if (file_exists($fileName)) {
            file_put_contents($fileName, $data, FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            file_put_contents($fileName, $header.$data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is $refUserId defined?

Comment: $RefUserid is the login of the user on the web, for example I want the file to output: at 15:01:01 the file will be named "TestUser-20-08-21-15-01-01-request.csv ".

Comment: I changed $RefUserid to $name but it's not working